# How to insert data into a form with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, automation

I have a web page that contains a contact form, I would like to use PHP to fill out the form predetermined strings and then submit the form.

The form itself returns a message that says it was either successful or not. I would like that message to then be mailed to a specific email (if it's not successful) with an alert.

This "script" will be a part of a cron job that will run daily to make sure that the form is working and sending emails through properly.

Comment: Try to use curl and have a look for the Post parameter

Answer (score 0):

`curl` can do this very easily.

```
$ch = curl_init()
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_POST => true
   , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'field1=val1&field2=val2'
   , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
   , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
   , CURLOPT_URL => '/path/to/form/recipient'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
mail('admin', 'Cron Result', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well

filling and submitting the form with php doesn't make sense.
Submitting a form in nothing more than an http call with parameters send via POST or GET.
So suggest is use curl in the php page you execute from crontab to make an http request to the php page that based on his business logic test if everuthing is fine and when needed send a mail notifications.

whith curl it's easy to send POST parameters as shown here http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php